# How to disable excel workbook backup creation when exporting to PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I created a Macro to save excel as a PDF. The code works for me, however, I want to disable the backup excel file saved (it creates a new workbook called Book1, Book2, etc. every time I save).

I know about `Workbook.CreateBackup=False`, but I don't know how to implement on an Exported file (versus a SaveAs). I've searched through multiple forums, but cannot find the answer.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim tsR As String
    Dim serialNo As String
    Dim xStrDate As String
    Dim myFileN As String

    tsR = "TS256359_Report_"
    serialNo = Range("N7") & ""
    xStrDate = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss AM/PM")
    myFileN = tsR & serialNo & "(" & xStrDate & ")"

     With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WC Worksheet").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Copy
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\e356881\Desktop\8540 Worksheets\" & myFileN, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I would like for when I save the file to PDF, the additional excel workbook is not created.

Comment: remove `ActiveSheet.Copy`?

Comment: That's the trick! Thank you!